Specify Explicit Topic for Debezium Kafka-Connect's Publication
Given the following debezium KafkaConnect configuration:
    class: io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
    tasksMax: 1
    config:
      plugin.name: pgoutput
      publication.autocreate.mode: filtered
      slot.name: debezium
      transformsMode: outbox
      transforms.outbox.type: io.debezium.transforms.outbox.EventRouter
      transforms.outbox.route.topic.replacement: ${routedByValue}
      key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      value.converter: io.debezium.converters.BinaryDataConverter
      value.converter.delegate.converter.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      value.converter.delegate.converter.type.schema.registry.url: 'http://cp-schema-registry.namespace.svc.cluster.local:8081'
      value.converter.delegate.converter.type.schemas.enable: false
      heartbeat.interval.ms: "60000"
      heartbeat.action.query: "INSERT INTO public.debezium_heartbeat (id, time) VALUES (1, NOW()) ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET time = NOW();"
      database.hostname: 'table.aws-us-east-1.domain.com'
      database.user: user
      database.password: password
      database.dbname: table
      topic.prefix: 'prefix'
      table.include.list: 'public.table'
      database.port: 5432

My debezium connector produces to the prefix.public.table Kafka topic.
Instead, I want this connector to produce to the foobar_bippy Kafka topic. What configuration must I change in order to achieve that?
One approach seems to be outbox-event-router approach, but I'm not inclined to use it given its apparent complexity and level of effort. This table will rarely change, so I fully accept the risk of tightly coupling debezium and the DDL of the table.
